# Template getID calling regular getID

Tags: c++, variables, static, initialization, local

I have seen that code somewhere and I don't know how it works. pls explain :(
My guess is that the template function is saving the state of other function.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

int getID() {
    static int id = 0;
    return id++;
}

template <typename T>
int getID2() {
    static int id2 = getID();
    return id2;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << getID2<int>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << getID2<int>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << getID2<double>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << getID2<double>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << getID2<int>() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
0
1
1
0
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that the functions most likely **do not** do what the original author intended. The first one, obviously, generates ever-increasing (unique for all practical purposes) IDs. The second one (template) creates a family of ever-increasing IDs, each in its own separate range, starting at an ID pulled from the first version. Except... except that isn't true because the two counters are not synchronized, so with high likelihood, ranges will _ovelap_. The "fun" thing about it is, that depending on the usage, it may actually "work".

Answer (score 1):

Each template call with its own type is its own function. Essentially, your code contains

```
int getID2_int() ..
```

and

```
int getID2_double() ..
```

as two separate functions. In each of these separate functions, you have

```
static int id2
```

which only gets initialized once, so getID gets called twice - once from the int version and once from the double version.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, different template specializations are *different* functions, i.e., `getID2<int>` and `getID2<double>` are different functions.

When you first call `getID2<int>()`, you initialize a `static` variable

```
static int id2 = getID();
```

In turns, this calls `getID()`, which initializes a `static int`

```
 static int id = 0;
```

and returns `i++`. `i++` is the post-increment of `i`, which means that `getID()` returns `i` (set to 0) and then increments `i` (to 1); because `i` is static, it will retain its value 1 on the next call of `getID()`.
The returned value 0 is stored in the static variable `id2` of `getID2<int>`.

When you call the second time `getID2<int>`, the initialization of `id2` is skipped, and `getID2<int>` just returns its value 0.

Now, when you call `getID2<double>`, `id2` gets initialized with the return value of `getID()`. This time, however, the static variable `i` of `getID()` is already initialized, and it equals 1. Hence `getID()` returns 1, and increments `i` to 2. The returned value 1 is passed to `getID2<double>`, which initializes its `static int id2` variable to `id2=1`.

At the next call of `getID2<double>`, `id2` is already initialized to 1, therefore `getID2<double>` just returns 1.

Answer (score 1):

A static variable of a function is initialized only once when the function gets the control the first time.

So when the function specialization `getID2<int>` is called the first time

```
std::cout << getID2<int>() << std::endl;
```

its static variable `id2` is initialized by the value of the static variable `id` of the non-template function by 0 (pay attention to that in the return statement of the non-template function there is used the post-increment operator

```
return id++;
```

So the returned value of the function is the value of the variable `id` before the increment.)

. So in the second call of the function template specialization

```
std::cout << getID2<int>() << std::endl;
```

the declaration

```
static int id2 = getID();
```

is skipped and the function again outputs `0`.

The same is valid for the function template specialization `getID2<double>` but in this case in the first call of the function the value of `id` is already was changed to 1. So all calls of the specialization returns the initialized static variable `id2` with the value `1`.

```
std::cout << getID2<double>() << std::endl;
```

Again in subsequent calls of the specialization the declaration

```
static int id2 = getID();
```

is skipped  because the static variable `id2` was already initialized.

Pay attention to that specialization of a template function are different functions.

From the C++ 17 Standard (9.7 Declaration statement)

> 4 **Dynamic initialization of a block-scope variable with static storage
>   duration (6.7.1)** or thread storage duration (6.7.2) **is performed the
>   first time control passes through its declaration**; such a variable is
>   considered initialized upon the completion of its initialization....